# "template argument 1 is invalid" when including a specific header

Tags: c++, templates, header, openfoam

I am trying to make a solver in OpenFOAM using reaktoro package with ThermoFun database:

```
#include "fvCFD.H"
#include <ThermoFun/ThermoFun.h>
#include <Reaktoro/Reaktoro.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    #include "setRootCaseLists.H"
    #include "createTime.H"
    #include "createMesh.H"
    #include "createFields.H"

    ThermoFun::Database database("databases/thermofun/aq17-thermofun.json");
    Reaktoro::ChemicalEditor editor(database);
    editor.addAqueousPhaseWithElements("H O Cl C Ca F Al Si K");
    editor.addMineralPhaseWithElements("H O Cl C Ca F Al Si K");
    Reaktoro::ChemicalSystem system(editor);
    Reaktoro::EquilibriumProblem problem(system);
    problem.add("H2O", 1000 , "g");
    problem.add("Calcite",1000,"g");
    Reaktoro::ChemicalState state = equilibrate(problem);
    state.output("result.txt");
}
```

But I get this error:

```
In file included from /opt/openfoam8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/setRootCaseLists.H:3:0,
                 from reakTest.C:7:
/opt/openfoam8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/listOutput.H: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/opt/openfoam8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/listOutput.H:33:31: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         << fvPatchField<vector>::dictionaryConstructorTablePtr_->sortedToc()
```

Here is what's inside `setRootCaseLists.H`:

```
if (args.optionFound("listVectorBCs"))
{
    Info<< "vectorBCs"
        << fvPatchField<vector>::dictionaryConstructorTablePtr_->sortedToc()
        << endl;
    listOptions = true;
}
```

Apparently, it has something to do with the `#include <ThermoFun/ThermoFun.h>`. If I don't include this header, it works fine.

Comment: `std::vector` is a template in the standard library. Do you have some vector that is not a std::vector? Perhaps the bug is some file with: `using namespace std;`

Comment: I think OpenFoam uses its own vectors (Foam::Vector). Can you help me fix this, please?

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible example